# How to change the default compression method in QGIS raster creation tools

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, compression

Tools which create new rasters in QGIS let you set the compression method, using GDAL's -co COMPRESS= method.
The "High Compression" is set by default to "DEFLATE" (and PREDICTOR=2).

I'd like to use better methods, like ZSTD as default. Whereabout in the software do I change that?

I didn't see anything in the custom settings.

[image]

Edit:

If I set the default option with the relevant parameters, it will not retain the values next time I run any raster creation tool, and will still show me blank parmeters.

[image]

Comment: You are in the right place. You can create a new profile or select an existing profile and edit or add the Name/Value pairs.

Comment: @user30184 I've tried that, but the default resets after every use.

Comment: This is where GUI methods (software) touch their limits. I am not sure if there is a way or not to this in QGIS. However, in my opinion, the best way is to copy the script from the toolbox history (for the settings which work best for you). And then use it for your future similar jobs.

Comment: Did you try `Settings-Options-GDAL-Raster driver options-GTiff`? The changes to preset options does not seem to be permanent when they are made in `Save as...`.

Comment: @user30184 Oh, wow, it's that simple! write it as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default settings can be edited and saved permanently through menu option

```
Settings-Options-GDAL-Raster driver options-GTiff
```

Preset options can be changed also when an image is saved with `Save as...` but those changes are not permanent.

Comment: Many many Terrabytes of disk storage would be saved, if that was the default setting. Alone from my yearly batch of GIS students, who produce massive amounts of bloated datasets, storing zeros in uncompressed Float32 Rasters :'D